# Binding calculated value to custom directive

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I'm having trouble when initializing the position for my custom draggable directive. I was supposed to make its position on the center of the screen. However, after I calculating, it only binds on what is on the data() which is (0,0). Here is my code below:

```
export default {
  directives: {
    Drag,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      },
      window: {
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
      },
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
    this.handleResize()
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  },
  methods: {
    handleResize() {
      this.window.width = window.innerWidth
      this.window.height = window.innerHeight
    },
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.position.x = this.window.width / 2
    this.position.y = this.window.height / 2

  },
}
```

On HTML:

```
 <div class="modal-wrapper" v-drag="position">
```

Comment: i think no issues in this code. Check v-drag directives code.

Comment: try `inserted`, `update` Hook Functions to update position vlaue in v-drag directive. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html